# Get the maximum value based on two columns values using foor loop in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, while-loop

I have fake table which I have created with 4 columns:
Farmer_name,crop_name,year,working_days

The table describes the crops that each farmer had in the past three years and the season length in this year :
[image]

(the red ones are the same grower)

```
>>>farmer   crop_name   year  working_days
   red       potatoe    2018   110
   red       onion      2019   120   
   red       onion      2020   130
   red       wheat      2019   70
   blue      coffe      2018   194
   blue      coffee     2019   115
```

I need to find for each farmer what is the biggest value of working day for each year.

e.g if for the red farmer in 2018 we have values in working_days of: 124,145,and 70, I would like to get new table which will look like this:

```
>>>  Farmer      year      working_days
       red        2018     145
       red        2019     190
       red        2020     175
       blue       2018     72
```

*the blue in the example is because I want to get it for all the farmers I have and not only for the red one.

I work more with python and I felt like for this I would like to use for loop but from reading I see that it's impossible in sql and the demand is to do it with SQL . I saw there is an option to use while loop but I don't know how to do it wwhen I have here two columns that needed to be taken into account (grower name+year).

I have seen examples to use the while loop as for:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
GO
```

(from here: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php)
(and also similar here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-while-loop-with-simple-examples/)
but I don't understand how to use counter in situation like this that I need the maximum value and I need also to check it for each farmer.

**My end goal: to get one table with all the farmers names' ,year and the biggest value of "working_days" for that year for each farmer.**

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Comment: @JimMacaulay just added (fake database I have created + added example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `max()` function and `group by` expression in the following way:

```
SELECT
    farmer,
    year,
    max(working_days)
FROM
    farmer_table
GROUP BY
    farmer,
    year
```

Comment: this isgives the right number of rows but it doesn't really take the maximum values (for the grower I show i nthe picture it gave the maximum value of 70 instead of 145)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of SQL which supports analytic functions, then `ROW_NUMBER` is the way to go here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Farmer, year ORDER BY working_days DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Farmer, year, working_days
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Another version, using joins, but not analytic functions, would be:

```
SELECT t1.Farmer, t1.year, t1.working_days
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Farmer, year, MAX(working_days) AS max_working_days
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Farmer, year
) t2
    ON t1.Farmer = t2.Farmer AND t1.year = t2.year AND
       t1.working_days = t2.working_days;
```

Note that in general solving this problem by iterating your records with a cursor is *not* the way to go.  SQL by its nature intends to be set based, meaning that a SQL query with already iterate over all records without the need for an explicit cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

```
select farmer, year, max(working_days) from table_name
group by farmer, year order by year;
```